# Loop over a list with delimiter different from comma

Tags: loops

I am trying to iterate over a list, the delimiter of which is not a comma. The reason for not using commas as delimiters is that they are part of the payload. Is there a way to iterate over a list in which the delimiter is a semicolon (or any other delimiter)?

So far, I have tried

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ls}[1]{\@for\tmp:=#1 \do{\tmp}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ls{(a,b);(c,d)}

\end{document}
```

Hence, I'd like to loop over the tuples separated by the semicolon, i.e. (a,b) and (c,d).

Edit: I was also trying to find some documentation on `\@for`, but I was not able to find any.

Comment: See the loop macros in `etoolbox`

Comment: @daleif would you like to turn your comment into a proper answer? I was writing one, when I saw your comment, so I decided to ask first :)

Comment: `\@for` is part of the latex format so `texdoc source2e` If you want to use `\@for` and a comma you can hide inner commas in `{}` so `\ls{{a,b},{c,d}}` would iterate over the two pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `etoolbox` has many interesting features, including making list parsers. See also the unstarred version.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\handler[1]{item: #1\par}
\DeclareListParser*\forsemicolonlist{;}
\forsemicolonlist\handler{(a,b);(c,d);(e,f)}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

For example, you can use this code:

```
\def\ls#1{\lsA#1;;}
\def\lsA#1;{\ifx;#1;\else \dosomething{#1}\expandafter\lsA\fi}
\def\dosomething#1{\message{I am doing something with #1}}

\ls{(a,b);(c,d);(e,f)}
```